# How can I concatenate the items into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I have this list :

```
a = [["Hello", "Good Bye"],["Country", "Test"]]
```

And I would like to concatenate the sub items I mean I would like to have this :

```
a = ["Hello Good Bye", "Country Test"]
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[' '.join(sublist) for sublist in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), it applies a function to all elements in a list.

```
>>> a = [["Hello", "Good Bye"],["Country", "Test"]]
>>> res = list(map(" ".join, a))
>>> res
['Hello Good Bye', 'Country Test']
```